# Class OfferSerializer missing "Meta.model" attribute

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to build offer management app in Django rest framework. So i made following serilizer

```
class OfferSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
             fields = {
             'id'
             'Name'
             'valid_from'
             'valid_to'
             'is_disabled'
           }
           fields = '__all__'
```

and when i passed following in jason format

```
     {
            "id":1,
            "Name" : "Discount Offer",
            "valid_from":"2021-05-21",
            "valid_from":"2021-08-21",
            "is_disabled":1
}
```

But i am getting error :- Class OfferSerializer missing "Meta.model" attribute
In above code i have created meta mode; but still why I am getting that error?

Update,
Now I have made changes in program
I have build model

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    valid_from=models.DateField()
    valid_to=models.DateField()
    is_disabled=models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serilizer.py

```
class OfferSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Offer  
        fields = ('name', 'valid_from', 'valid_to','is_disabled')
```

viewsets.py

```
class OfferViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=models.Offer.objects.all()
    serializer_class=serializers.OfferSerializer
```

router.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('Offer',OfferViewSet)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/',include(router.urls))
]
```

But I am still getting same error, Class OfferSerializer missing "Meta.model" attribute

Please help me

Comment: You haven't provided a model in Meta like the error says. Not sure what you mean by "meta mode" but add `model = Offer` to Meta or what ever your model is called

Comment: @IainShelvington i don't have model, I have predefined/set schema which is store in database

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a model associated with the serializer then switch from `serializers.ModelSerializer` to `serializers.Serializer`

Also, you Meta.fields is a `set` in your code, maybe that works aswell but in the docs they are using a `list` like so:
`['id', 'Name', 'valid_from', 'valid_to', 'is_disabled']`

Answer (score 1):

*When you use `fields` attribute of the **Meta** class in serializer or inherit from `serializers.ModelSerializer`, it means that you are writing a serializer for an existing model.*

If you have no predefined model and need a serializer, use the classic way like this :

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class OfferSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    valid_from = serializers.DateTimeField()
    valid_to = serializers.DateTimeField()
    is_disabled = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**NB**: It is up to you to have a validation about the unique constraint on the *ID*.